# How do I retrieve the users of a specific group or data store through OpenAm 11 SOAP (or REST) web-services?

Tags: openam

I have the following requirement: Retrieve the users from OpenAm which are members of a specific group. Alternatively, if possible, retrieve users defined in a specific data store. All this through web-services.

We have our own JDBC data store implementation which reads users from and authenticates users against our database. That works fine. The data store is one of two data stores in our sub realm. The other data store points to an LDAP.

Now I need to read the users (and later the user attributes) from users being defined in the LDAP data store, and only users of a specific group, if possible.

Previously we did that with wso2. There they had a web-service method that allowed you to retrieve users of a specific group only.

Currently I am looking into the IdentityServices web-service of OpenAm, and I am able to list all users of my realm, and get the attributes. But for performance reasons, it would be nice to be able to refine the search. Is that possible? Am I looking at the wrong web-service?

Regards,

Sascha